# Помогите, как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Помогите разобраться, как правильно?

- не каждая психика такое выдержит
- ни каждая психика такое выдержит

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с "ни" грамматически ошибочен. Другой вариант плох стилистически: с "психикой" (или напр. "здоровьем") не принято обращаться отвлечённо, как с самостоятельным счётным существительным ("каждая" или "через одну"), поскольку это принадлежность индивида.

> Не у всякого психика такое выдержит.

Answer (score 0):

**Правильно: Не каждая психика такое выдержит.**

Здесь НЕ ―  отрицательная, а не усилительная частица.

**Пример:**  "Известно ведь, что не каждая психика выдерживает дополнительные ощущения, открывающиеся потоки информации".
[Алексей Похабов: «Держите разум открытым»](http://www.tele.ru/liniya-sudby/aleksey-pokhabov-derzhite-razum-otkrytym/)

Дополнение

ПСИХИКА, 2. **Душевная организация, душевный склад; состояние нервной системы.** Здоровая, больная психика. У этой собаки травмированная психика. Давить на психику.

Понятие "психика", особенно в разговорной речи, имеет широкий спектр значений (например, состояние нервной системы), **поэтому не стоит усложнять синтаксис**, чтобы соблюсти некую условную точность выражений. Например, практически трудно по стилю предпочесть первый вариант  второму:
**Не у всякого психика** такое выдержит. Груз прошлого и будущего выдержит **не всякая психика.**